# Adding link into "Estimate Shipping" module in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

I have an OpenCart shop, and the customer the end-user to be able to contact the company if only "Pickup from Store" is available. Below is a mock-up of how it should look.

[a busy cat http://www.luof.co.uk/shipping.jpg](http://www.luof.co.uk/shipping.jpg)

Ideally, if delivery is available, the link should not appear if possible.

I have tried editing the shipping module in the admin panel, but doesn't have the options required. Therefore, I'm guessing there is some form of PHP/TPL file which I can edit to perform this function?

The URL in question is http://www.luof.co.uk/shop

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The template file you are looking for can be found in `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme/template/checkout/cart.tpl` - The template for the code itself is actually built up in javascript. Search the file for

```
if (json['shipping_method']) {
```

The code is just after that

Comment: Thanks for the help! Found the relevant code section, however, what "if" statement do I edit in order for the changes to be made? Or is it that single "if" statement that I have to edit? Thanks! :)